# How to optimize the code?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions that are basically the same - they iterate over some array.
The difference is what happens inside the loop.

```
    func1: function () {
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            result = result + array1[i].field1 + ', ';

        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
            return result.substring(0, result.length - 2);
        } else return ""
    },

    func2: function () {
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            result = result + array2[i].field2 + ', ';

        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
            return result.substring(0, result.length - 2);
        } else return ""
    },
```

What is the correct way to say make it just one function, or to make both inherit some common code?
I see a solution to make it just one function and provide different parameters:

```
func: function (array, fieldName) {
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result = result + array[i].[fieldName] + ', ';
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
        return result.substring(0, result.length - 2);
    } else return ""
},
```

But something tells me it's ugly. What is correct way to do it?

Comment: `array[i].[fieldName]` is just wrong; it’s supposed to be `array[i][fieldName]`. Other than that, it’s fine. That’s what parameters are for.

Comment: i think the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a better place for this question ?

Comment: Do you need compatibility with older browsers?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much easier than concatenating and truncating...

```
func: function(array, fieldName) {
    return array.map(a => a[fieldName]).join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Less and elegant code, but how does it stand up performance-wise?

Comment: @K3N worth a read ~ https://ryanpcmcquen.org/javascript/2015/10/25/map-vs-foreach-vs-for.html

Comment: @K3N This is one of the new `Array.prototype` methods. They are _the_ new and best way to iterate over arrays to get specific values. You can expect them to be optimized for speed across most implementations, because they’re built-in and they’re going to get used very often in the future. Therefore, `map` will have very fast performance in the long run.

Comment: @Xufox already love it :) +1 I was more concerned about the arrow part but jsperf seem to be down so I'll take the word for it :)

Comment: @K3N the arrow is just ES6 syntax. Performance wise, it would be no different to `array.map(function(a) { return a[fieldName] })`

Answer (score 2):

Old school:

```
function pluckAndJoin(arr, attr) {
  var i,
      len = arr.length,
      res = [];
  for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        res.push(arr[i][attr]);
  }
  return res.join(', ');
}

console.log(pluckAndJoin([{name:'Hello'}, {name:'World'}], 'name'));
```